# hadoop: FileSystem copyToLocalFile method fails to copy the whole file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I need each one of my cluster's nodes to retrieve a 1GB file from hdfs. I use FileSystem's copyToLocalFile method. But instead of the whole file (1GB) each node retrieves about 50MB of the file and then the code goes on. As a result my job fails. Why is this happening?Is there a way to "wait" until the whole file is copied to local fs?

EDIT: My mapper class checks if the file exists in node's local fs and if it is not it retrieves it.This is done in setup() function.

Comment: Are you first copying the file and starting the MapReduce job afterwards? Or does the job do any copying? Please post some information about your job/code.

Comment: Thank you harpun.I ve added some information

Comment: Is there any special reason for every mapper having to read a 1 GB file? The concept behind Hadoop MapReduce is that each mapper processes a part of the input file (so called `InputSplit`) and produces output for the reducers. So the usual approach would be to store the 1 GB file in HDFS and write a job, that will process it. The path to the file would be a parameter to the job. Since every node has a part of the file, ideally it is not necessary for any node to copy any data via network, but only process its local data. (I'm just making sure, whether you know about this.)

Comment: Harpun thank you again..I am aware ablout the things you tell me. What I m trying to implement is a map-side join in which each node should store the whole small table and read from it line by line and do the join with the records of the splits of the big table that each node reads from hdfs.

Comment: Can you share some code as to where you're doing this - and have you looked into using the Distributed Cache, this is exactly what it's designed for

Answer (score 0):

From your last edit:

> EDIT: My mapper class checks if the file exists in node's local fs and if it is not it retrieves it.This is done in setup() function.

What you're describing is exactly what the DistributedCache is designed for - it will ensure that the files are copied to each Task Tracker before any of your map / reduce tasks run on that node.

Comment: Chris thanks. I ve tried DistributedCache and I have the same resluts.To be more specific I add the 1GB file in DistributedCache and then I open it in setup() of each Mapper and read it line by line (record by record).From each record I extract the id and I do `id mod 8`. The result of the mod tells in which file split I should copy the record. For example if id mod 8 = 0 it the record should go to the file-split0 if it is 1 to file-split1. File splits are stored locally.From the way they created it is clear that the sum of file splits sizes should be 1 gb.

Comment: That's true for some nodes,but there are nodes where the sum of the size of the local stored split files is smaller, about 500 mb or smaller. So I ve tried both copytolocalfile and DistributedCache but I  miss some records both ways.

Comment: Please, please post some code to your original question, it's still not clear what you are trying to do